# Facebox not loading image

Tags: jquery, css, popup, facebox

I'm using [Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) for my popups.
However when loading big pictures it shows the Facebox but without the spinning circle.

The ["Facebox loading" thread](http://groups.google.com/group/facebox/browse_thread/thread/e17697d543a9192) has this solution:

```
$("#test2").click(function(){ 
       $.facebox(function() { 
            $.facebox.loading(); 
            $.get('whatever.php', function(data) { 
                    $.facebox.close_loading(); 
                            $.facebox(data); 
                            }) 
            }) 
       })
```

However I can't get this properly implemented for images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem.  It appears to be a bug due to the new layout.

I made the changes in the `loading` function, from the facebox.js:

FROM:

```
  $('#facebox .body').children().hide().end()
```

TO:

```
  $('#facebox .content').children().hide().end()
```